# EDIT:plotting the function, x and y must have the same first dimension

Tags: python

**UPDATE:**
Using the answer from before, I was able to call the function. Now, I tried to increase the difficulty a step-further.

I understand that using this works:

```
def sinesum(t, b):
     return sum(b*sin(n*t))
for i in range(0, 10, 1):
     b = i
     n = i
     t = i
     print(sinesum(i,i))
```

Although, I want to be able to plot it with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
plt.plot(t, sinesum(i,i))
plt.show
```

I get nothing, how do I plot with the function output as `y`?

when I remove `(i, i)` and include `(t, b)` I get

> x and y must have the same first dimension, but have shapes (20,) and (1,)

I understand that this is because the function only calls a single value, how do I get it so that `sinesum(i,i)` will return the right amount of dimensions for the plot?

Comment: Do you need to call the `f(x)` function inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate every value before plotting it:

```
res = []
for v in t:
    res.append(sinesum(v,b))

plt.plot(t,res)
```

or using list comprehension:

```
plt.plot(t, [sinesum(v,b) for v in t])
```

Comment: Can you give explain what's going on here? I'm not familiar with your approach

Comment: I am not sure what is the range of your values. I assumed that since you had an x_axys named t (same as the one inside function sinesum) that you wanted to calculate sinesum(t,b), with t ranging from -10  to 10. Could you tell me what is the interval of each value: t and b?

Comment: using your code I managed to figure it out. I used the `res.append(sinesum(i, i))` inside the `for` loop before the `print` function, whilst maintaing `res = []` as a variable to contain the output. Many thanks for your help, these suggestions are great!

Answer (score 1):

Did you meen?

```py
def f(x):
    return 4*x + 1

for i in range(100):
    print(f(i))
```